# New to javascript, how to assign an input value to a submit button?

Tags: javascript, function, input

I'm new to javascript and need help with a piece of my code. I am suppose to create a text box that a user can input a number and the function will then roll that many dice. I also need to set limits so a user can't enter -10 or 100 because it is only 1-6. So it looks like this:

```
var theInput = document.getElementById('num').value;
theInput = parseInt(theInput);
if (theInput < 1) { 
theInput="1"; 
} 
else if (theInput > 6) { 
theInput = "6"; 
}
```

The part I'm stuck on is how I am suppose to link a text box to this piece of code that will then run through my function for dice rolling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function SelectImage6() {
        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML ='';
        for(i=0; i<6; i++){
            roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            imgName2 = '../images/die' + roll2 + '.gif';
            document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML += 
            '<img alt="die image" src="' + imgName2+'" />';
            }


        }
</script>

<body>


<div style="text-align:center">


<input type="button" value="Click to Roll" onclick="SelectImage6();">

        <p id="outputDiv">
            <img id="dieImg2" alt="die image"
            src="../images/die2.gif" >


        </p>

    </div>
```

Where do I assign the var theInput within my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well first you should create the textbox in the html like this:

```
<input type="text" id="num">
```

Then have people push a button to start your javascript code. So use the button you already have. Then when the SelectImage6() function is called on the button click, you just put the top javascript code (the one checking the input) into the function SelectImage6() and you will have a nice function that does it all.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specifics of your question, it makes most sense to get the number of dice to roll inside the `SelectImage6` function.  To make things nice and clean, you might want to encapsulate that functionality:

```
// returns the number of dice the user entered.  if the user entered a non-numeric
// value, this function will throw an exception.  if the user entered less than
// one, the value will be clamped to 1, and if the user entered more than six, the
// value will be clamped to 6.
function getNumDice() {
    'use strict';
    var numEntered = parseInt( document.getElementById('num').value );
    if( isNaN( numEntered ) ) throw 'The number of dice must be numeric.';
    if( numEntered < 1 ) numEntered = 1;
    if( numEntered > 6 ) numEntered = 6;
    return numEntered;
}
```

I cleaned up your function a little bit.  "`theInput`" is a bit vague for a variable name, so I changed it to something more descriptive.  I handled the case where the user doesn't enter a number, and I consolidated the `document.getElementById` and the `parseInt` into one line.  Also, you were mixing types in your original code.  You use `parseInt` (which returns a numeric type), but then you would set `theInput` to a string.  This may not result in an error thanks to JavaScript's flexible type coercion, but it's bad practice regardless.

Now that you have that function, you can modify your `SelectImage6` accordingly:

```
function SelectImage6() {
    'use strict';
    var div = document.getElementById('outputDiv'); // cached for efficiency
    var html = '';
    var roll2, imgName2;
    var numDice = getNumDice(); 
    for( i=0; i<numDice; i++ ){
        roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        imgName2 = '../images/die' + roll2 + '.gif';
        html += '<img alt="die image" src="' + imgName2+'" alt="die" />';
    }
    div.innerHtml = html;
}
```

For `SelectImage6`, I made some changes (in addition to using the value returned by `getNumDice`).  First, you're repeatedly calling `getElementById` (once, unnecessarily, at the top of the function, then once for every dice rolled!).  Any DOM access is expensive, and if you can avoid doing it multiple times, you should.  Secondly, you're repeatedly modifying the `innerHtml` property which, depending on the complexity of your HTML, and your network latency, could cause flicker or other unpleasant effects.  What I chose to do instead was to build up the string first, then set it all at once.

In your original function, you were unwittingly using global variables (implied globals) because you didn't declare `roll2` and `imgName2` as variables.  I fixed that, and added `use strict` to your functions so this mistake will be caught in the future!  (My advice is to **always** set `use strict`.);

I hope this helps!  Welcome to the world of JavaScript.